# Problemas ao identificar tela de celular com css

Tags: css

Estou tentando montar um *box* de *login* responsivo. Onde ele tem `.css` para telas de monitor e outro para celular. O problema e que no celular não esta dando certo.

Faço o seguinte teste:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {
```

Se eu diminuir a janela no *browser* para menos de `550px` o `.css` muda, porém quando abro a página no meu iPhone 6 a verificação não funciona. Como identifico a tela de celular com *.css*?

```css
.box_login {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  width: 400px;
  color: #666;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  margin: auto auto 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 0 50px 0;
}
.box_body {
  margin: 30px;
}
.box_login_header {
  background: #0091FF;
  position: relative;
  height: 185px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.cont-lock {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
}
.cont-lock-img {
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-left: 62px;
}
.cont-lock::after {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -35px;
  border: 7px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-bottom-color: white;
}
.box_login h1 {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #cfd8dc;
  line-height: 35px;
}
.box_login button {
  width: 330px;
}
.box_login_footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  background: #0091FF;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0 0 0;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {
  .box_login {
    width: 95%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box_login">

  <div class="box_login_header">
    <div class="cont-lock">
      logo
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="box_body">

    FORM
  </div>

  <div class="box_login_footer">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você tem que inserir a tag `meta name="viewport"`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Ela é responsável por, além de outras coisa, redimensionar o *layout viewport*.

No *content* você especifica atributos da viewport e define seus valores, colocando `width=device-width`você diz que a resolução de renderização da viewport, em relação à largura, será igual a resolução do dispositivo.

Ou, em um futuro próximo, pelo css:

```
@viewport {
    width: device-width;
}
```

"Futuro", porque só quem têm suporte ao [CSS Device Adaptation](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-device-adapt/) atualmente é o Opera, o IE11 e o Edge14.
[CSS Device Adaptation - Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#search=%40viewport).

Comment: Muito obrigado, me ajudou pra ca****** hahaha